# Not getting exportLinks from google drive api

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to export a spreadsheet file from my drive to my computer. I want to achieve this by using the `google drive api`, using `exportLinks` from the file's metadata. The problem is that the data returned by the `Files: get` request does not contain `exportLinks`:

```
{
      u'mimeType': u'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
      u'version': u'34078',
      u'appDataContents': False,
      u'labels': {
        u'restricted': False,
        u'starred': False,
        u'viewed': True,
        u'hidden': False,
        u'trashed': False
      },
      u'explicitlyTrashed': False,
      u'etag': u'"BhHHITEi3P331vdo-oAOUKP5GTI/MTQ0Mzg4Mzk4Mzc5Nw"',
      u'lastModifyingUserName': u'Razvan Chitu',
      u'writersCanShare': True,
      u'owners': [
        {
          ...
        }
      ],
      u'id': u'1i9fjIOwX_ccEKadQvpB45ryGght9aMIS58S9b8O2v_c',
      u'lastModifyingUser': {
        ...
      },
      u'title': u'convertcsv.csv',
      u'ownerNames': [
        u'Razvan Chitu'
      ],
      u'lastViewedByMeDate': u'2015-10-03T18:16:09.495Z',
      u'parents': [
        {
          u'isRoot': True,
          u'kind': u'drive#parentReference',
          u'id': u'0AIEd4G-w3G0DUk9PVA',
          u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1i9fjIOwX_ccEKadQvpB45ryGght9aMIS58S9b8O2v_c/parents/0AIEd4G-w3G0DUk9PVA',
          u'parentLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AIEd4G-w3G0DUk9PVA'
        }
      ],
      u'shared': True,
      u'editable': True,
      u'kind': u'drive#file',
      u'markedViewedByMeDate': u'1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
      u'modifiedDate': u'2015-10-03T14:53:03.797Z',
      u'createdDate': u'2015-10-03T14:32:03.115Z',
      u'iconLink': u'https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_11_spreadsheet_list.png',
      u'embedLink': u'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i9fjIOwX_ccEKadQvpB45ryGght9aMIS58S9b8O2v_c/htmlembed',
      u'alternateLink': u'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i9fjIOwX_ccEKadQvpB45ryGght9aMIS58S9b8O2v_c/edit?usp=drivesdk',
      u'copyable': True,
      u'modifiedByMeDate': u'2015-10-03T14:42:57.087Z',
      u'userPermission': {
        u'kind': u'drive#permission',
        u'etag': u'"BhHHITEi3P331vdo-oAOUKP5GTI/uvD0nHQ6ksn74VXPBbBJCSAbI4Y"',
        u'role': u'owner',
        u'type': u'user',
        u'id': u'me',
        u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1i9fjIOwX_ccEKadQvpB45ryGght9aMIS58S9b8O2v_c/permissions/me'
      },
      u'spaces': [
        u'drive'
      ],
      u'quotaBytesUsed': u'0',
      u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1i9fjIOwX_ccEKadQvpB45ryGght9aMIS58S9b8O2v_c'
    }

// List of keys
mimeType
version
appDataContents
labels
explicitlyTrashed
etag
lastModifyingUserName
writersCanShare
owners
id
lastModifyingUser
title
ownerNames
lastViewedByMeDate
parents
shared
editable
kind
markedViewedByMeDate
modifiedDate
createdDate
iconLink
embedLink
alternateLink
copyable
modifiedByMeDate
userPermission
spaces
quotaBytesUsed
selfLink
```

I've followed the example here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#examples. The weird thing is that if I run the example there, the response contains `exportLinks`. Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try the 'Try It!' playground on the bottom of [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) for comparison?

Comment: Yep, and surprisingly I get the `exportLinks` from it.

Comment: Where you able to resolve this? I'm facing the same issue - exportLinks is absent in the metadata obtained via Python. Scopes are all in order.

Comment: Nevermind. Resolved it by replacing the scopes for metadata and file readonlys with drive readonly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add proper scope in order to access `exportLinks`.

It's certainly enabled by adding `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` to scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue for a while. I used the Quickstart guide and it defaulted to the read-only scope. I changed the scope to the least restricting one but it still did not work. exportLinks was not showing in the request, but it was showing up in the try it thing. I then set SCOPE variable to empty string, compiled and it gave an error. Then I reset SCOPE to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive then reran. The consent page came up, and now the exportLinks attribute is accessible.